# how to use decoder and motor drivers to power individual motors at 12V?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, voltage-regulator, pwm, decoder

I have a huge set of motors and they need to powered at specific times and at different voltage levels individually. Basic idea that I had, is to use a demux or a decoder to select the motors and then control them through PWM using any uC(preferably Arduino) and a motor driver. But I couldn't figure out how to connect them. Would anyone suggest any ways of executing the above connection or Can suggest a different way to tackle the main problem? The no. of individual control required is approx. 300.

[image]

Will the above approach work as to providing closed circuit to the selected coils only? And the PWM control can be provided to the driver through Arduino.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific than 'couldnt figure out how to connect them'. Are you talking their power (put the drivers in parallel), the control (how many separate channels), which demuxers to use (HC4052?) or whether to demux at power or control (so one driver per motor, or one per set of motors). How about you throw down a schematic of what you **have** figured out so far, and point to the part you don't understand.

Comment: @Neil_UK I wish to use the minimum no. of motor drivers possible, so what I desire is to power only those motors that have been selected by the demux or decoder. That is, I wish to select the motor 1st and then somehow provide it the 12V voltage from a single motor driver ( a single motor driver for all the motors).

Comment: @Neil_UK added the schematic, please do have a look.

Comment: Your question is missing details on motor type, current and uni-directional or bi-directional drive requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are describing logic-level devices which can only switch logic level signals. They are not capable of switching 12 V motor currents.

If you have only one motor driver then you have to switch the motors. This may be done with relays or, if they are DC motors and only run one direction then a transistor or MOSFET could be used to enable each motor by connecting one of its terminals to the 12 V power supply positive or common. Meanwhile the PWM from the motor controller could be connected to the other terminal of each motor.

Comment: this approach solved the problem, Thanks.